# Why if $Z/m\oplus Z/n = Z/mn$ then $(n,m)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Prove that if $Z/m\oplus Z/n = Z/mn$ then $(n,m)=1$.

I have proved the converse, but here there is something I am missing. Hints instead of full answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $(n,m)= d \not= 1$. Let $(a,b)\in Z/m \oplus Z/n$. Can you show that that $(a,b)^{\frac{mn}{d}}=e$?